# How to detect if app is being operating by automated testing tools?

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso, android-uiautomator

Sometimes, hackers may use automation tools, such as `Robotium、Espresso、UiAutomator2、Appium`, to automatically operate my customers' apps, which will **integrate our SDK**, to earn profits.

So how to detect if current app is being operating by such automated testing tools (except checking the service and process) **without editting the app itself**? Thanks~

Comment: Find any solution? thank you

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to remove all IDs, text descriptions and other helpers from the app. Even if there are IDs have multiple builds with different IDs or dynamic IDs. Other methods are:

To re-skin the app regularly to avoid automation using image comparisons. 
Have more captcha or other security methods to avoid automation.

Comment: How does one do that? Doesnt this impact app functionality?

Comment: IDs used for the UI elements are the meta data of the elements/objects of the app. They don't need to be static or even present in the first case at all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest way is the strict Proguard configuration when you make a release build.

If you are assuming somebody will create a script using Appium+Espresso/UiAutmator to communicate with your app, make sure you don't have the following in your **proguard rules**:

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.material.**
-keep class com.google.android.material.** { *; }

-dontwarn androidx.**.
-keep class androidx.** { *; }
-keep interface androidx.** { *; }

-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }

-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

In this case, your app simply won't be suitable for test automation.

Also, if you do have your own tests, make sure there is no way to start them for release APK. Mostly like no harm, but I have seen it once :)

Comment: Any update on regarding this?